# Spring boot applciation not taking controller classes throwing exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have converted an existing spring application into a Spring Boot application by adding plugins and Spring Boot dependency in pom.xml. This is my pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- tag::actuator[] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end::actuator[] -->

    <!-- Spring Security -->  
    <dependency>  
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>  
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>  
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>  
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>  
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>  
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>  
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>  
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>  
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security --> 

    <!-- odbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- odbc -->

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The following is my controller class:

```
@Controller
@ComponentScan("com.eg.example.controller")
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseDAO dao;

    /*some code */

}
```

The following is the DatabaseDAO.class

```
public class DatabaseDAO {
    /*dao sepcific code*/
}
```

Now after running the maven install, jar is build in the target folder and when I am running the jar from command prompt I am getting following errors:

> ERROR SpringApplication - Application startup failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eg.example.dao.DatabaseDAO com.eg.example.controller.HomeController.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.eg.example.dao.DatabaseDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) ~[spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109) ~[spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.9.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.9.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.9.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952) [spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.9.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941) [spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.9.RELEASE]
>   at com.ge.ideate.Application.main(Application.java:17) [gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar!/:na]
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
>   at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar!/:na]
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eg.example.dao.DatabaseDAO com.eg.example.controller.HomeController.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.eg.example.dao.DatabaseDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   ... 22 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ge.ideate.dao.IdeateDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.8.RELEASE]
>   ... 24 common frames omitted
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ge.ideate.dao.IdeateDAO com.ge.ideate.controller.HomeController.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ge.ideate.dao.IdeateDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
>   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
>   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>   at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
>   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
>   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
>   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
>   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
>   at com.ge.ideate.Application.main(Application.java:17)
>   ... 6 more

I was unable to figure out where the error is please help me on solving this issue. This is my servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.eg.example.*" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Ain't you missing servlet-context.xml definition in post? Please provide all the details.

Comment: Added servlet-context.xml. Please provide the solution. Thanks

Comment: Please include DatabaseDAO completely.

Comment: You mean database code may be a cause for exception?

Comment: Your main class is key to a Spring Boot application. It's typically used to configure your app, rather than using XML, including enabling component scanning. You also need to annotate your DAO with @Component for it to be picked up.

Comment: Well it looks like, your DAO is not picked up by Spring configuration. Can you ensure that it is annotated with @Component and also its package is included in the component scan.

Comment: yeah , after annotating the DAO with component scan i have successfully run the maven install and got the jar file . But the problem is with the jar file execution . I was not able to open any page..

Answer (score 2):

you should annotation `@Repository` above `DatabaseDAO` class. This errors cause by spring context cannot find bean name DatabaseDao to inject it into `HomeController` component.